# Is there a way to reach the subscription of a merged Observable (mergeMap/concatMap/exhaustMap)

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm doing a paginator with RxJS, I use a subject to centralize any time a new page is called. And on each event, I use exhaustMap to retrieve the page. That's prevent the getPage http call to be fired several time for the same page.

```
this._nextPage$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(nextPageNumber => this.getPage(nextPageNumber))
).subscribe();
```

But I'd like to also show a spinner on each http pending.

**With this code, how to reach the subscription of the merged http Observable ?**
(in order to bind a pending component to the subscription)

Thx in advance !

---

[EDIT]

I need/prefer using a Subscription that hold the pending state itself for 2 main reasons:

- I already use several custom components/directives based on Subscription
- As it's used in many different places I hopped to manage the pending state without too much boilerplate code ...

Here is a simple example of component displaying pending action

```
@Component({
  selector: 'anie-busy',
  templateUrl: './busy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./busy.component.scss']
})
export class BusyComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() subscription;
  isPending = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.isPending = true;
      this.subscription.add(() => this.isPending = false);
    } else {
      this.isPending = false;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe do operator in between to accomplish that.

```
this._nextPage$.pipe(
tap(()=>{//loading},
exhaustMap(nextPageNumber => this.getPage(nextPageNumber),
 tap(()=>{// stop loading})
).subscribe();
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this mainly because I already have systems that rely on `Subscription` but i don't see any other away.

Comment: FYI, with pipeable operator, you should use `tap` instead of `do`.

Comment: @Alexandre SIRKO don't quite understand what you mean rely on Subscription

Comment: I use Angular and I have several component to display pending state, they all accept a `Subscription` as Input. I then use add(aTearDown) to react according to the resolution of the Observable

Comment: got to see more code to tell what makes your case special. We often just slice and combine observable for various purpose.

Comment: I suppose that there is no way to reach/send back subscription nested inside a merge operator, then I will have to implement your solution.

Comment: You can alternatively use behaviour subject as a loading event bus in between without changing the current stucture too much. isLoading=new BehaviorSubject(flase); then use isLoading.next(true) in tap(). I normally use a shared service to control most of the logic flow with observables, then there's less need to pass event around different component, coz most of the time our component won't be reused and don't need a public API